# Can't install Krita

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, krita

I tried to install **Krita** but I always get the same error messages.

I already tried to install using

```
sudo apt-get -f
```

and also

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

but still get these errors:

```
necrosnake@necrosnake-BU5:~$ sudo apt-get install krita
[sudo] password for necrosnake: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
krita : Depends: libpoppler-qt5-1 (>= 0.24.5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
necrosnake@necrosnake-BU5:~$ sudo apt-get install libpoppler-qt5-1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created

or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpoppler-qt5-1 : Depends: libpoppler73 (= 0.62.0-2ubuntu2) but 0.62.0-2ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

As I mentioned I tried to install using the `-f` option and `autoremove` but I didn't succeed. That's why I tried installing manually the package  `libpoppler-qt5-1` but it didn't work.

What can I do now?

By the way I'm using Ubuntu 18.04LTS

[system details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oz1tv.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the complete output of the command: `sudo apt-cache policy krita` and `sudo apt-cache policy libpoppler-qt5-1` You seem to have a version conflict that must be solved by a human - it's that "You have requested an impossible situation" part of the error message.

Comment: Welcome Hernandez to **askubuntu**! Please avoid posting pictures as they contain only terminal output.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

First downgrade a dependency

```
sudo apt install libpoppler73=0.62.0-2ubuntu2
```

Second install missing library

```
sudo apt install libpoppler-qt5-1
```

Install Krita

```
sudo apt install krita
```